# How to solve Microsoft Office error 1402 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2007

I have installed Microsoft Office on my new Windows 7 64-bit system. Recently, it encounter some error and I tried to re-install it. It wasn't successful. So, I have to use Microsoft Install Clean Up to uninstall Microsoft Office. When I tried to install it again, I received this message:

> Microsoft Office 2007 encountered an error during setup.
>   Error 1402. Setup cannot open the registry key. {a bunch of long keys}. Verify that you have >sufficient permissions to access the registry or contact Microsoft Product Support Service for >assistance. For information about how to contact PSS, see {a *chm file}.

After that, I tried to run the setup as administrator but I ended up with the same error. So what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> Microsoft Install Clean Up to uninstall ... Microsoft Office 2007

Uh... why?

> *Warning* The Windows Installer CleanUp Utility is provided "as is" to help resolve installation problems for programs that use Microsoft Windows Installer. If you use this utility, you may have to reinstall other programs. Caution is advised.
>
> *Note* **We recommend that you do not use this utility with 2007 Office system products**. For help removing installations of 2007 Office system products, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:

Try the link they recommend: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971179/

Comment: Actually, I have uninstalled using Revo Uninstaller Pro. And I tried to install Office 2007 back but still getting the same error. I think it is register-related error. Do you have any recommendation to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928218/? Microsoft tell you not to use those tools.

Comment: I have tried. its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command-prompt (`cmd.exe`) and use the following command:

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script for fixing corrupted Office 2007 install on Windows 7 (written in autoit)

> [reg-add-everyone.zip](http://www.box.net/shared/7tyhr11ryn7socflvnu4)

The script goes through the registry and changes the permissions on all the registry keys needed for installing Office-2007 to "Full Control" by "Everyone".

After running this script I was able to install Office 2007.  I did have to make one manual pass to click checkboxes since Windows uses non-standard checkbox which Autoit recognizes as a "Button" so cannot click on it.

By default this updates all registry keys containing the string: "00F01FEC"

**Prerequisites:**

For this script to run correctly you must set up `regedit` as follows:

1. manually open the registry editor,
2. press  Ctrl-F to bring up the search dialog box
3. uncheck the boxes for "values" and "data"
4. make sure that the only box checked is for "Keys"

Comment: Answers should not rely on external files unless absolutely required (which isn't the case here).